# What would be a good hardware configuration for a Redis dedicated server?

Tags: redis

I am planning to configure Redis in Master/Slave configuration.

I have got three machines (8GB RAM, 8 cores), planing to to use one master and two slaves.

What would be the recommended hardware configuration for these machines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redis is not CPU intensive, so you should get at least 2 cores per server (one for redis, one for backups, maybe one more to do basic stuff on the server?), more is not really relevant. Redis is single-threaded.

Get as much RAM as you can as it defines the size of your store. Also making a dump consumes RAM so your true space size is less than you can think. Monitor your RAM usage to prevent surprises.

For RAM type, if it fails, redis fails and sometimes silently (consistency broken). If you need to be careful with your data always use ECC RAM, it is expensive but maybe less expensive than broken data in RAM accessed through redis causing unknown effects. Redis has no known checks against hardware errors from RAM, even if it is quite rare (less likely to happen than a broken hard drive) it does happen.